# Read string value from registry but the result contains some weird characters

Tags: c#, registry

I'm reading string values from Registry using `Registry.GetValue`, the result I get back seems to have some 'invisible' characters which I don't see from Registry Editor.

For example, `Registry.GetValue` returns `"London\0j"` but I expected it to be simply `"London"`, and in Registry Editor I can only see the value `"London"` and there doesn't seem to be anything at the end of the string. If I export this key to a .reg file it also only shows `"London"`. I don't have permission to write to the registry so can't test by importing the .reg file.

Apply `String.Trim` to the result doesn't work either.

What is this `"\0j"`?

Edit: code to read the key value

```
    var registryValue =
        Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\Netlogon\\Parameters",
            "DynamicSiteName", String.Empty);
```

The exported .reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Netlogon\Parameters]
"DynamicSiteName"="London"
```

Comment: Where do you see this "\0j"? In debugger?

Comment: Not only just the debugger, the returned string is actually `"London\0J"` when I print it out..

Comment: The actual characters "\", "0" and "j" or null character (\0) and letter "j"?

Comment: I would guess it's \0 and letter j as the length of the string is 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/microsoft/win32/registrykey.cs,c67ba10c47948465) `GetValue` uses `RegQueryValueEx` to read the complete value from the registry.

Then this data is converted into the target C# type according to the registry type that was returned (as output parameter) by `RegQueryValueEx`.

So what you see is what really was written to the registry. You don't see the `\0j` in regedit as this tool is implemented using zero-terminated strings. So regedit "thinks" the string ends at that `\0` and does not display it.

But since `GetValue` reads what *really is there*, you're output is correct. C# does not use `\0` as a string termination character.

Of course I can't tell you who wrote this data into your registry and if this is valid or not. (It could actually be used as some sort of weird hidden information by an app to verify that the value was written by this app)

Comment: Ah..that might be it. Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @Godsent I just verified with a little test. Writing `test\0j` (with _binary_ `0`, not the two characters `\ ` and `0`) to the registry and exporting it with regedit. Same result: `\0j` is not written to the *.reg file but c# `GetValue` reads it.